# Meaning of it and this

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "take this" and "take it"?
Is there any difference in their meaning or they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Is there a particular point of confusion for you here?  Is the verb "take" important to your understanding, or just the objects "this" and "it?"  I hate to see someone's first post get closed, but it seems likely with this broad a question presented with very little background.

Answer (score 3):

In general usage, you would say "take this" the first time you are offering something to someone; for example, if someone is about to go on a long, difficult journey, you might say

> "It's dangerous to go alone.  Take this."  *You pull a sword out of storage and offer it to them.*

You use "this" to establish that you are talking about a particular item and to identify the item in question (the actual identification is done with a gesture, such as pointing to the object or holding it out for them to take).
After the object which is "this" has been identified, you can refer back to that object as "it":

> "No, I don't think I'll be needing a sword for this trip,"  they reply.
>   "Oh, trust me.  Take it,"  you say.

You can also use "take it" any other time you are encouraging someone to take a previously-identified thing, whether you are the one who has offered it or not:

> "Jane, I just got a job offer, but I'm not sure what to do," said Bob.
>   "Take it," said Jane.  "It can't be worse than what you're already doing."